# Error installing ffmpeg on ubuntu: opus not found using pkg-config

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg

When I try to install ffmpeg on my ubuntu 14.10 machine, I keep getting this:

> ERROR: opus not found using pkg-config

at this [step](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu#ffmpeg):

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure \
  --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \
  --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" \
  --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
  --bindir="$HOME/bin" \
  --enable-gpl \
  --enable-libass \
  --enable-libfdk-aac \
  --enable-libfreetype \
  --enable-libmp3lame \
  --enable-libopus \
  --enable-libtheora \
  --enable-libvorbis \
  --enable-libvpx \
  --enable-libx264 \
  --enable-nonfree
```

I've followed all the previous installation steps and it went all successful. I'm really new to Ubuntu. Could anybody give me a hint?

Answer (score 13):

This helped for me...

```
apt-get install libopus-dev
```

Comment: To improve the quality of your answer, please include an explanation of what you believe their problem to be and how your answer improves the situation.

Comment: +1 but actually your answer without Calvin's answer isn't efficient. so both answers should be merged into one.

Answer (score 7):

I added this to the ./configure line, and it seemed to fix it:

```
--pkg-config-flags="--static"
```

Comment: +1 but actually your answer without John's answer isn't efficient. so both answers should be merged into one

Answer (score 4):

I solved this on Fedora by install the `opus-devel` package.

Answer (score 1):

1- first start fresh again and delete what you have done: (copy and in terminal press right button of the mouse to paste )

```
rm -rf ~/ffmpeg_build ~/ffmpeg_sources ~/bin/{ffmpeg,ffprobe,ffplay,ffserver,vsyasm,x264,x265,yasm,ytasm}
sudo apt-get autoremove autoconf automake build-essential cmake libass-dev libfreetype6-dev \
  libmp3lame-dev libopus-dev libsdl1.2-dev libtheora-dev libtool libva-dev libvdpau-dev \
  libvorbis-dev libvpx-dev libx264-dev libxcb1-dev libxcb-shm0-dev ibxcb-xfixes0-dev mercurial texinfo zlib1g-dev
sed -i '/ffmpeg_build/c\' ~/.manpath
hash -r
```

2- now update your server :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

3- install build tools for your server to build ffmpeg :

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

4- now follow the steps in this [link](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu)

Comment: Thanks! After installing `apt-get install libopus-dev`, I still got the error `opus not found using pkg-config` when retrying make. But after I deleted everything up with `git clean -xffd && git submodule foreach --recursive git clean -xffd`  and restarted the build process again, it worked!

Answer (score 1):

This was the only code worked to me

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

[reference](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/3280#issuecomment-255709990)